# Copy Data from one open Workbook into another open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Following code:

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
If Left(wB.Name, 21) = "Open Order Monitoring" Then
    Set Wb1 = wB
    Exit For
End If
Next

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(1, 39)).Copy wb2.Sheets(2).Range("B5")

End Sub
```

The macro should copy data from a open workbook with variable name (open order monitoring[...]) and paste into the second sheet of the workbook I run the macro from.

But the line:

```
Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(1, 39)).Copy wb2.Sheets(2).Range("B5")
```

gives me an error. can someone solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be your Range-Chaining? `Range("A2").Range(...` or your `.Cells` Notation?

Comment: After I posted this, I noticed this too. But didn't solve the error

Comment: Ok, the Range-Chaining could be OK (I think the first is simply ignored). But What about the `.Cells` and `.End` thing. I see no containing with-block

Comment: `wb1.Sh.Cells.Copy` `wb2.Sh.Range("A1").Paste` to copy the full content of the sheet? I don't know if that is your intent, or if you just want a specific portion of the sheet?

Comment: I wanted to copy the whole table of 39 columns starting in cell A2. That was the code for a variable row count. Can you please tell me what I have to change in this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since:

- it's always safer to use fully qualified range references (down to workbook and worksheet ones). especially when you're dealing with multiple workbooks and/or worksheets
- should you only be interested in pasting values, it's faster (and safer, too) use `Range1.value = Range2.Value` instead of `.Copy()` method of `Range` object.

then, here follows a possible code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
        If Left(wB.Name, 21) = "Open Order Monitoring" Then
            Set Wb1 = wB
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then '<~~ check if you actually found the needed workbook
        Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

        With Wb1.Sheets(1)
            Set rngToCopy = .Range("A2:AM2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
        wb2.Sheets(2).Range("B5:AN5").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: do you know how i can implement `Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit` in this code? it seems like excel only copies the values of the sheet if edit is enabled. I open the workbook from outlook so its in protected mode. Greetings

Comment: never made use of it. I guess msdn help for [ProtectedViewWindow Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822367.aspx),  [ActiveProtectedViewWindow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195068(v=office.15).aspx) and [ProtectedViewWindow.Edit Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838457.aspx) could help you

Answer (score 1):

Pls try with below code

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
    If Left(wb.Name, 21) = "Open Order Monitoring" Then
        Set Wb1 = wb
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
    Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AM2").Copy wb2.Sheets(2).Range("B5") 'Edited here
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! But `Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy wb2.Sheets(2).Range("B5")` still gives me an error because the size of the copy area and the size of the paste area are not the same size. The area i want to copy is a table that starts in cell A2 and has 39 columns (Column AM).

Comment: `Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)` has two drawbacks:1) would return `Wb1.Sheets(1)` range from its "A2" cell down to some row (see point 2)) of it whose index is defined by `ActiveSheet` column A actual content; 2) `Range("A2").End(xlDown)` would pick the last non empty cell of column "A" after cell "A2" only if both there are no empty cells between "A2" and the last non empty cell of column "A" (otherwise it returns the first non empty cell after "A2") and there actually is some non empty cell in column A after "A2" (otherwise it returns the last cell down the sheet)